# Gatsby build that isn't accepted by Netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I just updated my app with **gatsby develop** command. No problem.
Then I made a **gatsby build** command. No problem.

As always, I manually took my src/public folder and *dragged and dropped* it into the production section of Netlify.

Instead of the expected update, this is what I got:
[a requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed][1]

Does anyone know what this is about? Can anyone fix this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJVRp.png

Answer (score 0):

Just make a proper deploy using Gatsby Cloud with Netlify configured as Hosting instead of copy/pasting the folder.

1. Install [gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud/) in your project
2. Sign-in to your Gatsby Cloud account at [gatsbyjs.com](https://gatsbyjs.com)
3. Create a new site, import your project repo with GitHub, BitBucket...
4. Add environment variables (if any)
5. Deploy the site on Gatsby Hosting

Once done, just switch your hosting provider from Gatsby Cloud to **Netlify** and deploy everything again.

[image]

From now on, whenever you will push to your repo a build will automatically be executed and deployed. Moreover, you can set different webhooks, for example, you can trigger a build whenever some content on your CMS is updated.

**Pros**

- It is free
- You don't need to `gatsby build / gatsby serve`. Just focus on development.